# Randomly select items from two equally sized tensors

Tags: indexing, pytorch, slice, tensor

Assume that we have two equally sized tensors of size `batch_size * 1`. For each index in the batch dimension we want to choose randomly between the two tensors. My solution was to create an `indices` tensor that contains random `0` or `1` indices of size `batch_size` and use those to `index_select` from the concatenation of the two tensors. However, to do so I had the "view" that `cat` tensor and the solution ended up to be quite "ugly":

```py
import torch

bs = 8
a = torch.zeros(bs, 1)
print("a size", a.size())
b = torch.ones(bs, 1)

c = torch.cat([a, b], dim=-1)
print(c)
print("c size", c.size())

# create bs number of random 0 and 1's
indices = torch.randint(0, 2, [bs])
print("idxs size", indices.size())
print("idxs", indices)

# use `indices` to slice the `cat`ted tensor
d = c.view(1, -1).index_select(-1, indices).view(-1, 1)
print("d size", d.size())
print(d)
```

I am wondering whether there is a prettier and, more importantly, more efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting two answers that I got over at the [PyTorch forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/randomly-select-items-from-two-equally-sized-tensors/96411/)

```py
import torch

bs = 8
a = torch.zeros(bs, 1)
b = torch.ones(bs, 1)
c = torch.cat([a, b], dim=-1)
choices_flat = c.view(-1)
# index = torch.randint(choices_flat.numel(), (bs,))
# or if replace = False
index = torch.randperm(choices_flat.numel())[:bs]
select = choices_flat[index]

print(select)
```

```py
import torch

bs = 8
a = torch.zeros(bs, 1)
print("a size", a.size())
b = torch.ones(bs, 1)

idx = torch.randint(2 * bs, (bs,))

d = torch.cat([a, b])[idx] # [bs, 1]
```